# How to collect data in SQL Server via web services?

Tags: sql-server, xml, web-services, rest, powerbi

I'm new to data warehousing and the Microsoft SQL Server in general.

I would like to build a data warehouse on SQL Server and publish the reports in Microsoft Power BI. The dataset is not too big so I don't think it makes a difference whether using SQL Database or SQL Data Warehouse, would it. Instead, I would make this dependent on which is easier to configure for Web Service data feed.
That is, my data input would come via scheduled REST web service requests, XML or JSON, triggered and run on the server.
I would like to store them in some relational tables, no cubes or other fancy design at this point, and call on the tables in Power BI.

What is the best way to start out? Can you recommend any tutorials for such a setup and the web service requests?

Comment: Why bother with SQL? Power BI is much better at calling web services.  Save yourself a lot of time, money and code.

Comment: Is there any other way than via Power Query? (https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/03/26/working-with-web-services-in-power-query/) That approach requires a local client and (for reasons of security, better) stores access credentials on said client. I would like to run with a full cloud setup.

Comment: That blog post is 3 years old, Power BI only went GA last year. Ref www.powerbi.com for general info.  Scheduled refresh with cloud credentials is via one of their Gateway options: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/

Comment: I've been testing Power Bi for the last 3 months and based on half a dozen MS tickets, I confirm that a) Power Bi Online does not support any HTTP requests at all, b) Power Bi Desktop does support Web calls, but only via Power Query, but even then no token based authentication (because Power Query cannot deal with nonce and timestamp) and c) Power Bi Gateway supports nothing but Basic and Windows authentication, no OAuth or HTTP Headers in general (hence no custom authentication). Simply put, Power Bi is pretty useless integrating with any web services except for the 10 or 20 services offered.